# What are the current lowest TCP latencies one can accomplish in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, real-time, nio

We are currently using a multithreaded solution for a high performance TCP server handling 20 simultaneous connections. Our average latencies run around **200 microseconds per message** and we have been struggling to tame the GC activity which can produce **1ms+ outliers**. `Low latency is our utmost goal` for this server and we are aware that our current numbers are bad. We are evaluating single threaded approaches so we can have all these 20 connections handled by a single thread.

What is the current floor for TCP latency in Java, in other words, how fast can two machines exchange messages in Java through a TCP socket over a 10Gb network?

Comment: I'd suggest three things: 1/ Test with a trivial program just sending and replying to messages with fixed messages, so as to measure the latency, 2/ switch to a GC-less language, and 3/ use the same number of threads as there are logical cores, so as to avoid process switching (also assign preferentially one thread per core).

Comment: 2 is not relavant. TCP latency isn't really affected by choice of language. But definitely test a trivial program and see what the base latency is.

Comment: I'm not sure about you, but the last time I wrote a java TCP server (20 to 150 connections), the latency was less than 100ms. I get the feeling you're just having bad luck with your packet routing. You can try doing `Socket.setNoDelay(true)` though, sometimes that can reduce latency.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. There are many things that contribute to "networking statistics". In addition: what does it help you, when somebody gives you a number ... that this person achieved in a local, "laboratory" environment. I think, it might make more sense for you to either isolate "limiting" factors in your infrastructure ... or maybe to put up the essentials of your code at http://codereview.stackexchange

Comment: @Aify, microseconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: At these time frames the network card and its drivers (polling vs. interrupt drivven) and thread scheduling may have a measurable impact on your average times. If you want to tame the GC you also might want to look into Azul's pauseless collector. Maybe you should test against localhost to establish a lower baseline. And use a profiler/perf tools to check context switches, you want to avoid those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A multithreaded server is not the way to go for latency and 200 micros is indeed too high. For ultra-low-latency network applications it is mandatory to use a single-threaded, asynchronous, non-blocking network library. You can easily handle these 20 socket connections inside the same reactor thread (i.e. network selector) which can be pinned to a dedicated and isolated cpu core. Moreover, if using Java, it is mandatory to use a network library that leaves zero garbage behind since a cleaning GC activity will most likely block the critical reactor thread introducing the bad outliers you are observing.

To give you an idea of TCP latencies you can take a look on [these benchmarks](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/04/coralreactor-performance-numbers/) using [CoralReactor](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/coralreactor/), which is an ultra-low-latency an garbage-free network library implemented in Java.

```
Messages: 1,000,000 (size 256 bytes)
Avg Time: 2.15 micros
Min Time: 1.976 micros
Max Time: 64.432 micros
Garbage created: zero   
75% = [avg: 2.12 micros, max: 2.17 micros]
90% = [avg: 2.131 micros, max: 2.204 micros]
99% = [avg: 2.142 micros, max: 2.679 micros]
99.9% = [avg: 2.147 micros, max: 3.022 micros]
99.99% = [avg: 2.149 micros, max: 5.604 micros]
99.999% = [avg: 2.149 micros, max: 7.072 micros]
```

Keep in mind that 2.15 micros is over loopback, so I am not considering network and os/kernel latencies. For a 10Gb network, the over-the-wire latency for a 256-byte size message will be at least 382 nanoseconds from NIC to NIC. If you are using a network card that supports kernel-bypass (i.e. SolarFlare's *OpenOnLoad*) then the os/kernel latency should be very low.

**Disclaimer:** I am one of the developers of CoralReactor.

Comment: Did you replace the entirety of NIO's socket stack or just parts of it?  Would like to see the benchmarks with code and the comparison against vanilla java.

Comment: The latency list you provide is for TCP loopback, while the author asks for 10Gb network.